# Svg Icon in anchor Tag is Clickable but not working in Microsoft Edge or IE 11

Tags: css, react-tsx

I have a svg icon in my anchor tag in which i have a click event for anchor tag in my React application.My issue is like when i click on anchor tag its is working fine both in edge and chrome. But when i click on svg icon its is working fine in Chorme but not working on Edge.

```
switch (action.type){
            case ToggleActions.NAVBAR_TOGGLE:
                // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
                console.log('Toggle button is hit' + event.target);
                return{
                ...state,
                toggleState: !state.toggleState,
            };

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
  setNavBar: () => dispatch(setNavBarToggle()),
});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Sidebar);

<ToggleButton
          onClick={this.props.setNavBar}
          id='navigationPanelButton'
          title={openClosetooltip}
        />
```

Comment: You may want to set `pointer-events` to `none`, like `.myAnchor .mySvg { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: Thanks @AndyHoffman Its worked for me, But is there any other solution in React for this fix.

Comment: I would need to see a lot more code than this. Can you put something up on CodeSandbox?

Comment: i have added the Code

Comment: I have used pointer-events to none